# Laravel4 route pattern error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I´m using laravel 4 for a cms project, and i´m having some problems with my routes...

These are my current routes

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@showNews');
Route::get('/logout', 'UserController@logout');
Route::resource('/login', 'UserController');
Route::resource('/user', 'UserController@index');
Route::resource('/user/{route}', 'UserController');


// Routes that shows us the pages...
Route::get('/{page}', 'IndexController@showPage');
Route::get('/{page}/{id}', 'IndexController@showPage');
```

To my user routes i have a custom router that routes the user information around, not really a problem. But all of that works great, but when i try to navigate to "/test" Wich would link to a test page, it gives me this error.

```
Route pattern "/user/{route}/{{route}}" cannot reference variable name "route" more than once.
```

It comes up to router logic, and i´m fairly new to laravel. Is there a way for me to work around this problem? It´s a collision between the user/route and the /route wildcards.

Answer (score 7):

```
Route::resource('/user', 'UserController@index');
Route::resource('/user/{route}', 'UserController');
```

The problem is that you are using `Route::resource` to declare the routes, while by using `Route::resource` you are actually declaring a RESTful controller with a table of actions to be handled by Laravel automatically. You are using it incorrectly.

See the [docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) to see which routes are handled in the background (and hence the source of the conflict):

Take a look at the table called **Actions Handled By Resource Controller**

For any route handler that is not within the table you will have to declare separate routes. Something like:

```
Route::get('foo/filter/{filterName}/{filterValue}',
        array('as'=>'filteredroute','uses'=>'FooController@filter'))
```

As a summary, `Route::resource` enables you quick **CRUD RESTful** access.