# Laravel 4 routing: Cannot use variable name more than once

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm having an issue with Laravel 4 routing.  I am trying to create two sets of routes:

```
domain.com/meetings/aa, al-anon, etc.
domain.com/meetings/day/sun, mon, tue, etc.
```

Here is what I am specifying in my routes file:

```
Route::resource('meetings/day/{dayName}', 'Meetings_DayController');
Route::resource('meetings/{fellowshipName}', 'Meetings_MeetingController');
```

I need to be able to pass variables to my resourceful controllers.  But I am getting this kind of an error, no matter what order I put the routes in:

```
Route pattern "/meetings/fellowship/{fellowshipName}/{{fellowshipName}}" cannot 
reference variable name "fellowshipName" more than once.
```

Not only that, but those two routes cause other, undeclared routes to give the same error.  My 404 route doesn't kick in for some reason.  Ideas, anyone?  I've tried everything I can think of. If I could match a three-letter string with the day controller route, that would work, but I can't figure out the regex for a three-letter string in Laravel.  `\w{3}` doesn't work.

Comment: What does `php artisan routes` gives you?

Comment: It believes the bad routes exist.  It must be because I'm working resourcefully.

Comment: That's what the issue seems to be.

Answer (score 6):

You are using `Route::resource` incorrectly. You can't (and should not) pass a variable to a resource controller. Instead You will need to declare a new route with the verb you need and the parameter. `Route::resource` only creates several pre-handled routes for you for quick CRUD RESTful access

See the answer to similar situation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19608572/385402